# Can't access to mail attachments in mail app via apple script

Tags: macos, applescript

Let's assume that in the following code

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell first account
        tell first mailbox
            set myMessage to first message
            set myAttachment to mail attachments of myMessage
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

the first message of the first mailbox of the first account actually has attachments. Let's further assume that the account in question is a GMail account (maybe that proves relevant) and that I am trying this on El Capitan.

On the "set myAttachments" line I always get the error "error in apple event routine, -10000" (losely translated from German). I have read in old threads that there was indeed a bug in the access to attachments. But I also saw a new thread that was talking specifics about how to best handle them (no mentioning of having no access at all).

What am I missing? Does it work? Maybe in general but not with GMail? Do I have to do something specific?

Thanks!

Sandro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The exact syntax for this is "mail attachement of myMessage" (without "s").
The script bellow is working perfectly on my side for selected emails:

```
tell application "Mail"
activate
set ListMessage to selection
repeat with aMessage in ListMessage
    set AList to every mail attachment of aMessage
    repeat with aFile in AList
        if (downloaded of aFile) then
            -- do something with aFile 
        end if
    end repeat -- next file
end repeat -- next message
end tell
```

Are you sure the the message with attachement is in your first account/first mailbox?

Comment: I have switched to your code now, as it obviously simplifies the selection of a message to test with. I works, so thanks for getting me on track ("mail attachments" works as well btw). But it still doesn't work on the original message (thread) I tried it on. I have tried others as well. Those "messages", that contain some back and forth aggregated under one GUI item seem to be the culprits. I can correctly see all messages of the thread and iterate over them, but the the get mail attachment part fails. Ideas?

Comment: Mail's AppleScript dictionary does not handle threads/conversations, but only messages.
Also, the way GUI displays the conversation is not the way Mail sort the messages : Mail sort per thread and then only per date. Therefore your "first email" may not be the first email you see on GUI. I think this is the issue you're facing.

Comment: I do now have one conversation selected when I run the script. I can see in apple script that there are two messages and I know that both have attachments. To be clear: I don't care about the conversation as such, I only want to be able to get to the messages in it. And I can see the message objects alright, I simply can't access their attachments. I have added the additional step of retrieving the message we are currently looping over by its id, I can't access the attachment on that one either.

Comment: I never worker with conversation: could it be the the attachment you see belongs to an other mail in the same conversation ? For sure, syntax above works for messages with real attachments. Then only logical answer is that your message has no attachment. Remove the conversation mode , select message with attachment and try the script.

Comment: I switched off conversation mode (called something like "Include related mails"/"Zugehörige E-Mails einbeziehen") and then I only saw one message in the GUI, but still two messages in apple script! That got me thinking and I remembered that I had been playing with the "redirect" functionality on that mail. That seems to be the problem. Works well on other emails (even if they appear as conversations or if one is the forward of the other). I can live with that. Case closed, thank you! :-)

Comment: > The exact syntax is "mail attachement of myMessage" (without "s").  FALSE.  One of AppleScript's “key design features” is to allow plurals like this!

Comment: I do see the -10000 error despite "display by thread" being disabled and the mail being a regular, non-redirected mail. The error message reads: " To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info." I checked the permissions of the attachments folder and of course the owner has full permission on all subfolders (even tried with read permission for others on the whole subtree). My account is an IMAP (non-Gmail) account and the attachments are properly downloaded.

Comment: Can you explain at which line of the script you have the -10000 error ?